# Training a Fuzzy Distance for Clustering later

Tags: clustering, feature-selection

I have a set of strings $ s_i \in S $ and associated labels $ y_i $, where $ y_i $ could possibly be null.

There are many labels, but the cardinality is much smaller than the strings.

$$
1 << |\{ y_i \}| << |\{ s_i \}|
$$

Given 2 strings $ (s_i, s_j) $, I want to train a model $ \nu: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ that computes,

$$
Pr(y_i = y_j | s_i, s_j) \propto e^{-\beta ~ \nu(s_i) \cdot \nu(s_j)}
$$

Effectively, $ \nu $ converts the string into a real vector such that can be used to cluster strings.

With $ \nu $, I would store my strings in my database with a Spatial Index so that I can search for related strings quickly.

Has this been done before? Can you please provide references to applicable research?

---

Also, https://hackernoon.com/chars2vec-character-based-language-model-for-handling-real-world-texts-with-spelling-errors-and-a3e4053a147d is basically what I was thinking.

Comment: $\nu(s_i) \cdot \nu(s_j)$ is a dot product (vector multiplication)?

Comment: @rapaio Yes. Edited to make that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is training an embedding space that includes both the strings and the labels as entities. Example algorithms are doc2vec (where the doc is the label) and StarSpace.

The result is a dense vector representation that can be used with common distance metrics like L2 and cosine distance.

Comment: Will these perform when I have ~10k labels? My label space grows with my data volume.

Comment: Ah. I think something like this would work https://github.com/facebookresearch/StarSpace#docspace-document-recommendation. Thanks!